# Laravel mongoDB group by combine with where in

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, group-by, where-in

Here is my current code

```
    $results = Post::whereIn('category_id', $category_ids)
        ->raw(function($collection) {
            return $collection->aggregate([
                [   
                    '$group' => [
                        '_id' => '$user_id',
                        'count' => [
                            '$sum' => 1
                        ]   
                    ]   
                ],  
                [   
                    '$sort' => [
                        'count' => -1
                    ]   
                ],  
                [   
                    '$limit' => 10
                ],  
            ]); 
        });
```

I'm trying to get the posts that linked with certain categories, but this `$results` return all the posts.

How to modify this into `where in` + `group by`?

### Edit (2016-07-14 10:13am)

**Category**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("578489618a8920afcb3f4de2"),
    "updated_at": ISODate("2016-07-13T06:21:40.700Z"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2016-07-12T07:16:49.913Z"),
}
```

**Post**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("578499629a89202fcb3f4de3"),
    "user_id": "578299629989e02fcb3f4de3",
    "title": "How to deal with MongoDB",
    "category_id": "578489618a8920afcb3f4de2",
    "updated_at": ISODate("2016-07-12T07:16:50.512Z"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2016-07-12T07:16:50.512Z")
}

{
    "_id": ObjectID("578499629a89202fcb3f4de3"),
    "user_id": "578299629989e02fcb3f4de3",
    "title": "It's so weird~",
    "category_id": "578489618a8920afcb3f4de2",
    "updated_at": ISODate("2016-07-12T07:16:50.512Z"),
    "created_at": ISODate("2016-07-12T07:16:50.512Z")
}
```

So 1 *category* has multiple *posts*, I want to list out each user has how many posts, and sort by descending order.

Now the grouping & sorting already works, just cannot filter particular category_id

**Expected output**

```
| User  | Total posts |
|-------|-------------|
| Smith | 11          |
| Ivy   | 8           |
| Paul  | 3           |
```

Comment: Can you please provide a document from the collection you are trying to query? Can you please put the result you want displayed afterwards?

Comment: @suecarmol already update the document structure

Comment: Pretty messed question though... In the first section you asked how to filter by category (or something like this) and then you showed the nonsense desired output which have nothing to do with first part of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, based on your (weird) collections and if I did understand it well, it should be something like this:

```
<?php 

$category_ids = []; //categories goes here

$results = Post::raw(function($collection) use ($category_ids) {
    return $collection->aggregate([
        //where in...
        [
            '$match' => [
                'category_id' => ['$in' => $category_ids]
            ]       
        ],  
        [   
            '$group' => [
                '_id' => '$user_id',
                'count' => ['$sum' => 1]   
            ]   
        ],  
        [   
            '$sort' => ['count' => -1]   
        ],  
        [   
            '$limit' => 10
        ],  
    ]); 
});
```

The first stage of pipeline uses `$match` and `$in` in order to filter posts where `post.category_id` is in `$category_ids`.
I should do the trick!